# msys not flushing output

Tags: mingw, msys, mintty

I'm using mingw with msys and mintty on windows. I have a problem that msys and mintty are somehow not flushing output until a command is finished. This means I can't really run any interactive programs.

For example, if I have in `C`:

```
printf("Test\n");
```

the output won't appear until the program has terminated. However, if I have:

```
printf("Test\n"); fflush(stdout);
```

then the output appears immediately. If I use msys without mintty or the windows console, then everything works normally.

So my question, what's going on with msys and mintty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be an issue when *msys* uses the *rxvt* shell under a number of scenarios.  In cases where I see this problem, I ask msys to use the native Windows shell for its console.  For example:

```
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat --no-rxvt
```

I thought that modern MSYS installations default to using the native shell as MSYS developers seem to prefer it.  I have other issues with the native shell that drive me to use the *rxvt* shell, so I do infrequently run into this issue.

```
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat --rxvt
```

I find that the *rxvt* shell usually works fine except for certain applications that are built as "console" utilities meant to run from a command-line.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked for me was to precede the command with `winpty` ...

```
$ winpty java ClassName
```

---

It causes unbuffered output to be 3x slower and buffered output to be 5x slower (in my case, with Java).

---

To always have a command invisibly invoked by `winpty` ...

```
$ cd ~
$ pwd -W
```

... add the following line to `.bashrc` ...

```
alias java="winpty java"
```

... then restart terminal and ignore the (one-time) warning message.