# asyncio DatagramProtocol does not print to console but does so in sublime text window

Tags: python, sublimetext3, stdout, python-3.6, python-asyncio

I have the following minimal client code:

```
class Client(asyncio.DatagramProtocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        print(transport)
        self._transport = transport
        req = {
            'action': 'join',
            'x': 123,
            'y': list(range(5))
        }
        self._transport.sendto(
            dumps(req)  # dumps is bencode the dict
        )
        print('sent join')

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        print('lost')
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.stop()
        raise exc

    def error_received(self, exc):
        raise exc

    def datagram_received(self, data, addr):
        print('addr', addr)
        data = parse_packet(data)
        with open('f', 'a+') as fp:
            fp.write(str(data) + '\n')
        print(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    listener = loop.create_datagram_endpoint(
        Client,
        remote_addr=('127.0.0.1', 9999)
    )
    transport, protocol = loop.run_until_complete(listener)
    loop.run_forever()
    transport.close()
    loop.close()
```

In my console, when I run the `client.py`, none of the `print` statements above are shown in console. However, the data sent from my UDP server is being received at the client correctly. The file `f` contains the content as sent by the server.

The same program, when run inside the Sublime Text window (using <kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd>) shows the print statements in build result window.

Comment: If this is on Linux, does it help if you close and reopen your console application, and then run the program?

Comment: @user4815162342 surprisingly, it doesn't happen in linux. Only windows mingw shell. Cant even reproduce it on Windows cmd-prompt

Comment: Try adding `sys.stdout.flush()` after each print.

Comment: @user4815162342 yeah, that works. Why is mingw not flushing for asyncio loops? other programs work fine.

Comment: @user4815162342 nevermind, I think it is because of https://stackoverflow.com/q/35109086/1190388